# Lagom's embedded Kafka fails to start after killing Lagom process once

Tags: scala, lagom

I've played around with `lagom-scala-word-count` Activator template and I was forced to kill the application process. Since then embedded kafka doesn't work -  this project and every new I create became unusable. I've tried:

- running sbt clean, to delete embedded Kafka data
- creating brand new project (from other activator templates)
- restarting my machine.

Despite this I can't get Lagom to work. During first launch I get following lines in log:

```
[warn] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {wordCount=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
[warn] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {wordCount=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
[warn] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {wordCount=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
[warn] a.k.KafkaConsumerActor - Consumer interrupted with WakeupException after timeout. Message: null. Current value of akka.kafka.consumer.wakeup-timeout is 3000 milliseconds
[warn] a.k.KafkaConsumerActor - Consumer interrupted with WakeupException after timeout. Message: null. Current value of akka.kafka.consumer.wakeup-timeout is 3000 milliseconds
```

Next launches result in:

```
[info] Starting Kafka
[info] Starting Cassandra
....Kafka Server closed unexpectedly.
....
[info] Cassandra server running at 127.0.0.1:4000
```

I've posted full server.log from lagom-internal-meta-project-kafka at https://gist.github.com/szymonbaranczyk/a93273537b42aafa45bf67446dd41adb.

Is it possible that some corrupted Embedded Kafka's data is stored globally on my pc and causes this?

Comment: Perhaps wiping your temp folder (C:\Users\sbarancz\AppData\Local\Temp\) might help?

Comment: Hi @Szymon, this remains an open issue. See https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-scala/issues/4 . The problem is related to the embedded Zookeeper (needed by the embedded kafka) not closing gracefully. In the link provided there's more info and workarounds.

Comment: All Kafka's data is stored in `target/lagom-dynamic-projects/lagom-internal-meta-project-kafka`, deleting that should fix it.  There is definitely no global store.

Comment: @JamesRoper Could you please make it into the answer?

Answer (score 12):

For future reference, as James mentioned in comments, you have to delete the folder `lagom-internal-meta-project-kafka` in `target/lagom-dynamic-projects`. I don't know why it's not get deleted automatically.